# Difference between the return values of tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.img_to_array and tf.image.decode_jpeg

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I have a task to load and extract feature embeddings from images. I've working solutions that utilize two different ways of loading the image:

1. `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img` to load the image itself and then use
   `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array` to turn it into an array.
2. `tf.io.read_file` to read the raw file and then use `f.image.decode_jpeg` to decode it and turn it into an array.

During coding, I found that both ways of turning an image into an array return different results! And as a result, different feature embeddings are returned after model inference. Since I use the embedded results to cluster similar images, I've found that due to the difference in embedding I'm getting different clusters.

**Question:**

- Which method of loading images should be used and why?
- Why the results are different and how to make them the same?

**CODE:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from efficientnet.tfkeras import EfficientNetB0 
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import urllib.request

model = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling="avg")
IMG_SIZE=[224,224]

def read_image1(path):
    raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw, channels=3, dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE')
    image = tf.image.resize(image,IMG_SIZE)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    return np.array(image)

def read_image2(path):
    img = image.load_img(path,target_size=IMG_SIZE)
    arr = img_to_array(img)
    return np.array(arr)

def embedings(arr, model):
    arr4d = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=0)
    embeds=model.predict(arr4d)
    return embeds

url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Thai-Ridgeback.jpg'
pic_name='test_picture.jpg'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,pic_name)

arr1=read_image1(pic_name)
arr2=read_image2(pic_name)

embs1=embedings(arr1, model)
embs2=embedings(arr2, model)

img1 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(arr1)
img2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(arr2)

def compare_arrays(arr1,arr2):
    print(f'Shape is the same? {arr1.shape==arr2.shape}')
    print(f'Arrays are equal? {(arr1==arr2).all()}')

compare_arrays(arr1,arr2)
compare_arrays(embs1,embs2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results are different because when you use `tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)`, image values are normalized by the MAX value of the input dtype. ([convert_image_dtype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype)), also `tf.image.resize` default interpolation method is "bilinear" ([resize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize)) while `tf.keras.utils.load_img` ([load_img](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img)) defaul is 'nearest'.

I edited your code like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import urllib.request

IMG_SIZE=[224,224]

def read_image1(path):
    raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw, channels=3, dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE')
    image = tf.image.resize(image,IMG_SIZE, method='nearest')
    image = tf.cast(image, 'float32')
    return np.array(image)

def read_image2(path):
    img = image.load_img(path, target_size=IMG_SIZE)
    arr = img_to_array(img)
    return np.array(arr)

url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Thai-Ridgeback.jpg'
pic_name='test_picture.jpg'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,pic_name)

arr1=read_image1(pic_name)
arr2=read_image2(pic_name)

def compare_arrays(arr1,arr2):
    print(f'Shape is the same? {arr1.shape==arr2.shape}')
    print(f'Arrays are equal? {(arr1==arr2).all()}')

compare_arrays(arr1,arr2)
```

> Shape is the same? True

---

> Arrays are equal? True